# Overflow creates a small gap between content and padding

Tags: html, css, overflow

I was working on my website when I noticed a difference in width on one side of the content and the other. I checked if there was any margins or padding, and if the centering was set right. (I use `flexbox` here and everything was also fine)

Then I noticed a small gap between the padding and the actual content of a div and tried hovering it with the inspect tool within Chrome but couldn't select it.. I then found out it was because of the scroll bar:

[This is when overflow is set to auto or scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMnEk.png)

[And this is when it's  set to hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCMzT.png)

[Also without the custom scrollbar, seems to be the same width as the scrollbar itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JECJS.png)

I'm really confused about why this is and couldn't find anything about it online (probably searching for the wrong things...)

I did found out that when setting it to overlay it fixed the problem. But then also quickly found out that when changing every `overflow: scroll;` to `overflow: overlay;` in PhpStorm it started giving errors about deprecation.

So now I'm a bit stuck, is there a way around this issue or is this just how it is with scrollbars?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.